# M2.2 PHP7 CLI silent fails

Tags: magento2.2, php-7, cli

I've updated from 2.1 to 2.2

Getting no response from magento CLI under PHP 7.0.27

/opt/cpanel/ea-php70/root/usr/bin/php bin/magento deploy:mode:show -vvvv
(returns nothing, appears to do nothing)

If I try using PHP5 then it at least gives an error:

/opt/cpanel/ea-php56/root/usr/bin/php bin/magento deploy:mode:show -vvvv
Magento supports 7.0.2, 7.0.4, and 7.0.6 or later. Please read http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v1.0/install-gde/system-requirements.html

(Have cleared var: rm -rf var/cache/*; rm -rf var/di/*; rm -rf var/generation/*; rm -rf var/page_cache/*; )

Any ideas why magento has gone silent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We had the same issue just now and can confirm that after hours of trying a heap of different ideas including the things you've tried so far, it turned out to be a memory limit issue in php.ini.

Ours was set at 32mb which the CLI clearly didn't like.  We increased it and it instantly fixed the issue for us.